# JavaScript Errors when Loading NextGEN Gallery

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am using [NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) and [NextGEN GalleryView](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-nextgen-galleryview/).

***(Editors Note: Not sure what this sentence means)***
But I can't get the image those image was hidden.

When I check the css and js files, all of file are included when I check in firebug the below error is shown:

```
jQuery.timer is undefined
...for: http://192.168.1.210/hotel.com/wp-content/plugins/nggGalleryview/j...

jquery...r=1.1.2 (line 144)
jQuery("#ngg-gallery-1-133").galleryView is not a function


easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
```

Comment: i know this question got down vote but i dont mind becz i tried to find the solution for this probelm

Comment: your question was/is very poorly written. Please try to use proper grammar/spelling as it makes questions easier to understand/answer I wrote a comment in the question about the sentence I didn't understand. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GalleryViews plugin hasn't been updated in a while. jQuery has changed a lot since then. You'll most likely need to either downgrade jQuery (not recommended by any means) or upgrade the plugin's JavaScript to work with later versions of jQuery. It looks like there aren't newer versions of the scripts so you may have to either do custom modifications or ditch the plugin.

Comment: can you suggest me any gallery plugins for the own themes.